# Easy way to check precedence of ( "and", "or") in python

Tags: python, boolean

I have a python list like this

```
[True, "and", False, "or", False, "or", True ....]
```

How to operate them and find the boolean value (True and False or False or True ...) efficiently ?

I know and has more precedence than or. So I know about the way where we break the list about every or and take or of booleans computed from each list.

I want to know is there a more easy way to do so ?

```
if my_list = [True, "and", False, "or", False, "or", True ] this will output
True as (True and False) or False or True = False or False or True which is True. 

if my_list = [True, "and", True, "or", False, "or", False ] this will output 
True as (True and True) or False or False = True or False or False which is True

if my_list = [False, "or", False, "and", False, "and", True ] = False or False which is False
```

Comment: I am having hard time in figuring out what you're trying to do. Could you please add the expected output and your attempted solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you expecting to get? Could you show your code or any your tries?

Comment: If the only possible array elements are True, False, and & or -- there's probably a pretty simple evaluator that simply recurses with the remainder of the array when it finds an `or`.

Comment: if my_list = [True, "and", False, "or", False, "or", True ]

this will output True as (True and False) or False or True = False or False or True which is True.

and if my_list = [True, "and", True, "or", False, "or", False ]

this will output True as (True and True) or False or False = True or False or False which is True

if my_list = [False, "or", False, "and", False, "and", True ] = False or False which is False

Comment: The way to do this is to use the shunting-yard algorithm and effectively turn this into reverse polish notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will be faster, but:

```
l = [True, "and", False, "or", False, "or", False, "or", True, "and", False, "or", False, "or", False]
eval(' '.join([ str(z) for z in l]))
```

result:

```
False
```

Comment: Assuming that the input comes from a trusted source, the above is probably the least hacky and most Pythonic way to do this.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Using `eval` the most Pythonic way to solve this, seriously?

Comment: The OP wants to evaluate some logical operators. `eval()` evaluates. `ast.literal_eval()` wouldn't work, because `and` and `or` aren't literals. Do you know of anything in `ast` (or elsewhere) with parsing that focuses on this particular kind of expression?

Comment: Thanks @Iliyan This seems correct. Better than my hacky way.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I am sorry, you are right, this is probably one of the rare cases where `eval()` is actually the best way to solve the problem, as you said the `ast` module does not allow to evaluate such expressions. My apologies.

Comment: @Delgan - No problem. I'm comfortable with heavy resistance to `eval()` solutions, because, as you say, it is rarely a good option.

Comment: For extra assurance you could `assert all(x in {True, False, "and", "or"} for x in lst)` before running `eval`

Comment: @Daenyth - Assertions can be turned off. It's better to use `if...: raise...`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do operator precedence is through the [shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), which requires a stack:

```
def evaluate(e):
    ops = {'and': 1, 'or': 0} 
    op_stack = []
    output = []
    for i in e:
        if i in ops:
            while op_stack and ops[op_stack[-1]] > ops[i]:
                output.append(op_stack.pop())
            op_stack.append(i)
        else:
            output.append(i)
    op_stack.reverse()
    output.extend(op_stack)

    stack = []
    for i in output:
        #print(stack, i)
        if i in ops:
            a, b = stack.pop(), stack.pop()
            if i == 'and':
                i = a and b
            else:
                i = a or b
        stack.append(i)
    return stack[0]

>>> evaluate([True, "and", False, "or", False, "or", True])
True
>>> evaluate([True, 'or', True, 'and', False])
True
```

The other way to do operator precedence is a recursive [precedence climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser) algorithm:

```
ops = {'and': 1, 'or': 0}

def tokenizer(l):
    for i in l:
        o = yield i
        while o:
            yield None
            o = yield o

def evaluate(token, prec=0):
    lhs = next(token)

    while True:
        op = next(token, None)
        if op is None or ops[op] < prec:
            if op: token.send(op)
            break

        rhs = evaluate(token, ops[op]+1)
        #print(lhs, op, rhs)
        lhs = lhs and rhs if op == 'and' else lhs or rhs
    return lhs

>>> evaluate(tokenizer([True, 'or', True, 'and', False]))
True
>>> evaluate(tokenizer([True, "and", False, "or", False, "or", False, "or",
...                     True, "and", False, "or", False, "or", False]))
False
```

With the prints:

```
>>> evaluate(tokenizer([True, "and", False, "or", False, "or", False, "or",
...                     True, "and", False, "or", False, "or", False]))
True and False
False or False
False or False
True and False
False or False
False or False
False or False
False
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could use `map`, [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
l = [True, "and", False, "or", False, "or", True]
res = list(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, bool), l))

print(res)
[True, False, True, False, True, False, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this should be the simplest (less elegant) solution

```
expression = [True, "and", False, "or", False, "or", True]


def eval_expr( value1, operator, value2):
    if operator == 'and':
        return value1 and value2

    else:
        return value1 or value2


result = None

while len(expression) != 1:
    v1 = expression.pop()
    op =  expression.pop()
    v2 = expression.pop()
    partial_result = eval_expr(v1, op, v2)
    expression.insert(0, partial_result)
    result = partial_result

print result
```

Comment: Doesn't take into account operator precedence, e.g. `True or True and False`, should evaluate to `True` if `and` has higher precedence and `False` if `or` has higher (or equal) precedence.

Comment: Yeah, u're right it missing. Thank you for notice me it :)

Answer (score 0):

@Iliyan 's answer is correct. Less hacky than me.

I came up with a trick to do so.

my_list = [True, "and", False, "or", False, "or", True]

1. I created a file temp.py
2. Entered all values in list of my_list in order space separated in temp.py
3. Executed temp.py
4. Deleted temp.py

Kind of a hack ;)

Comment: @Iliyan's answer does pretty much this, only without needing to create a file first.